# How to parse HTML tbody data into Python in tabular format

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parser, python-beautifultable

I am new to python and I am trying to parse this data into  tabular format in Python. I have considered examples but unable to get desired result.

Can someone please help me on this

```
<tbody>
<tr><td>Kupon in %</td><td>36,520</td></tr>
<tr><td>Erstes Kupondatum</td><td>03.07.2017</td></tr>
<tr><td>Letztes Kupondatum</td><td>03.04.2022</td></tr>
<tr><td>Zahlweise Kupon</td><td>Zinszahlung normal</td></tr>
<tr><td>Spezialkupon Typ</td><td>Zinssatz variabel</td></tr>
```

Need this data in this way :

Kupon in %              36,520
Erstes Kupondatum       03.07.2017
Letztes Kupondatum      03.04.2022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in two ways 1. Using list comprehension and 2. using for loop
both produce the same result its on you to choose.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<tbody>
<tr><td>Kupon in %</td><td>36,520</td></tr>
<tr><td>Erstes Kupondatum</td><td>03.07.2017</td></tr>
<tr><td>Letztes Kupondatum</td><td>03.04.2022</td></tr>
<tr><td>Zahlweise Kupon</td><td>Zinszahlung normal</td></tr>
<tr><td>Spezialkupon Typ</td><td>Zinssatz variabel</td></tr>"""

#1
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
print(' '.join([td.text for td in soup.find_all('td')]))

# 2 
tags = []
tr = soup.find_all('td')
for td in tr:
  tags.append(td.text)

print(' '.join(tags))
```

> Output: Kupon in % 36,520 Erstes Kupondatum 03.07.2017 Letztes Kupondatum 03.04.2022 Zahlweise Kupon Zinszahlung normal Spezialkupon Typ Zinssatz variabel